# Why can't I build and then run my container locally

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have a multi stage `Dockerfile`

```
# Base Build
FROM alpine:3.7 AS base
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs
WORKDIR /root/app
COPY . .

ARG TARGET_ENV
COPY .env.$TARGET_ENV .env
RUN rm .env.*

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0
RUN npm install --only=production
RUN cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Prod Build
FROM base AS release
COPY --from=base /root/app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=base /root/app/package.json .
COPY --from=base /root/app/package-lock.json .
COPY --from=base /root/app/dist .
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 3000
```

I'd like to build my container and then run it locally.

It builds just fine but when I run it a hash is output, but the container is not running.

[image]

```
docker build --build-arg TARGET_ENV=local -t express-app .

docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -it express-app
```

Comment: If you remove the `docker run -d` option it will start in the foreground, and presumably promptly exit.  Does that print anything interesting?

Comment: Use `docker container ls -a` to show exited containers. Include `docker inspect` and `docker logs` on the container id.

Comment: Shouldn't  release refer from alpine:3.7 rather than base ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container could be crashing on start.

Check the output of `$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -it express-app` for error messages.